# What are the different LWC's for Uploading Files?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have seen developers using two different components (both LWC I think) for uploading.

Differences:

1. Control 1

   1. Button text is **Select Files**
2. Control 2

   1. Button text is **Upload Files**
   2. After choosing a file, it shows a red button: Delete File

However, I can only find one Upload control [here in SalesForce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation)

Answer (score 2):

They are `lightning-file-upload` and `lightning-input type="file"`. The former uploads files and has a UI, the latter only selects files, and you can read those files through JavaScript.